# How to call 404 page not found from view.phtml

Tags: 404-page, magento-1.4

I am developing a logic to accept sku of any product as value of a parameter `skuval`. In view.phtml

```
$spProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuval);

   if(!$spProduct) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("test");
        echo "This gets printed when sku is incorrect";
    }
```

Then redirecting user to product page. If the product does not exist, it shows a blank page instead of *404 page not found error*

**How do I redirect user forcefully to 404 page?**

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to add logic like this to a template file. Template files are only for displaying your block (in this case `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`). So what you want is a rewrite of the `Mage_Catalog_ProductController` class, since this handles all requests to the product detail page.

This also has another huge benefit. As you can see in that class, it does an `initProduct` call on the product helper. This method loads a product. So if you don't rewrite the controller before that point (or maybe rewrite this method itself), you first load a product, which might not exist, and then load the actual product you want, based on `$skuval`. That's a performance issue, since loading a product is slow.

So if you need your product pages to "listen" to the product's SKU to load, you should rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_ProductController::_initProduct()` method or the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProduct()` method, so it will also check if it can load a product based on the SKU. Keep in mind that when you rewrite the helper, the added functionality will be added to all code that uses this functionality (like `Mage_XmlConnect_CatalogController`).

If you want to know how to rewrite stuff in Magento, [Inchoo wrote a pretty useful blogpost about it back in 2013](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

The following code can redirect you to 404 from controller. Check if it will be helpful:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
$this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
```

Comment: It does nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
if (/** your custom logic goes here **/) {
$this->norouteAction();
return;
}
```

Comment: It says "There has been an error processing your request"
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::norouteAction(Array
(
)
)